# Check if values are those same objects

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm pretty new to Dart and I got some problems with understanding what is going on under the hood. I've simple code like this:

```
void main() {
  String s1 = "test1";
  StringBuffer sb = StringBuffer();
  sb.write("test");
  sb.write("1");
  String s2 = sb.toString();
  print(identical(s1, s2));
  print(s1 == s2);
  
  int a = 1;
  int b = 1;
  print(identical(a, b));
}
```

result of this code is 3x true

Which is little tricky for me. As I understands all variables refers to some values, and since == operator is expected to return true, I'm little confused why identical also return true. If I would use code like:

```
String s1 = "test1";
String s2 = "test1";
```

Then I would expect that there is compiler optimization for immutable strings. But since I combine it via StringBuffer I would expect that I got two different values in memory. I suspect that identical uses == operator internally... Why I'm curious: I'm working on app which will use sets of tags. And I'm not sure If should I create some pool of strings and checks if some strings are already created and reuse it or just spawn strings and Dart has it's own string pool?

Comment: The result of `identical(s1, s2)` for the `StringBuffer` case is surprising, but it seems to be true only for the web (such as with DartPad), and not with the Dart VM.  I would guess that it's true due to some optimization to cache JavaScript-backed strings at runtime.

Comment: Hi, good point. I performed additional tests on mobile platform and in such situation identical returned false both for strings and integers. So this is situation which I expected in the first place.